# How to return a value from a call to a smart contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

Is there any examples available to return a value from a call that modifies the onchain storage?

Returning values from reads is of course not a problem, but it was mentioned getting a return from a call is possible too.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you mean by getting the return value but here is an example:

```
export function incrementCounter(): i32 {
  let newCounter = storage.getPrimitive<i32>("counter", 0) + 1;
  storage.set<i32>("counter", newCounter);
  logging.log("Counter is now: " + newCounter.toString());
  return newCounter;
}
```

In the frontend you can get the value by

```
let a = await contract.incrementCounter();
```

Here is the fiddle https://studio.nearprotocol.com/?f=m4fcztid8.